# setting state not working in react in a weird way

Tags: reactjs

I made a hook to interact with my api:

```
import { useContext, useCallback } from "react";
import { toastContext } from "../trds";

export default function useAPIHook(){

    const launchToast = useContext(toastContext);

    const returnFunction = useCallback(async ({
        user, url, fetchOptions = {}, okCallback = () => {}, failedCallback = () => {}
    }) => {

        const idToken = await user.getIdToken();
        const apiResponse = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}${url}?idToken=${idToken}`, fetchOptions);
        const apiReturn = await apiResponse.json();

        if(apiResponse.ok) okCallback(apiReturn);

        else{

            if(apiResponse.status === 400)
                launchToast(apiReturn.error, 'error');
                
            else{
                console.log(apiReturn.error);
                launchToast('Something went wrong. Contact the developer!', 'error'); 
            }

            failedCallback();

        }

    }, [launchToast]);

    return returnFunction;

}
```

and then the users hook:

```
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { userContext } from "../contexts/user";
import { toastContext } from "../trds";
import useAPIHook from "./useAPIHook";

export default function useUsers(){

    const currentUser = useContext(userContext);
    const api = useAPIHook();
    const launchToast = useContext(toastContext);

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        (async () => {

            await api({
                user: currentUser,
                url: '/users',
                okCallback: (returnedUsers) => {
                    setUsers(returnedUsers);
                },
                failedCallback: () => {
                    launchToast('Failed while fetching users!', 'error')
                }
            });

        })();
        
    }, [api, currentUser, launchToast]);

    const createNewUser = async (userData) => {

        await api({
            user: currentUser,
            url: '/users',
            fetchOptions:{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(userData)
            },
            okCallback: (newUser) => {
                setUsers(prevState => [...prevState, newUser]);
                launchToast('New user has been created!', 'success')
            },
            failedCallback: () => {
                launchToast('Failed while creating user!', 'error')
            }
        });

    }

    const updateUser = async (userData) => {

        await api({
            user: currentUser,
            url: `/users/${userData._id}`,
            fetchOptions:{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(userData)
            },
            okCallback: (updatedUser) => {
                setUsers(prevUsers => {
                    return prevUsers.map(user => user._id === updatedUser._id ? updateUser : user);                  
                });
                launchToast('User has been updated!', 'success')
            },
            failedCallback: () => {
                launchToast('Failed while updating user!', 'error')
            }
        });

    }

    const deleteUser = async (userData) => {

        await api({
            user: currentUser,
            url: `/users/${userData._id}`,
            fetchOptions:{
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(userData)
            },
            okCallback: (deletedUser) => {
                setUsers(prevUsers => {
                    return prevUsers.filter(user => user._id !== deletedUser._id);                  
                });
                launchToast('User has been deleted!', 'success');
            },
            failedCallback: () => {
                launchToast('Failed while deleting user!', 'error')
            }
        });

    }

    return { users, createNewUser, updateUser, deleteUser }

}
```

my problem is that in the createNewUser function at okCallback, the state wont update with the newUser pushed to the state. nothing happens, like no errors, nothing. I debugged newUser 100 times and its good. setting the users state in the other functions (updateUser, deleteUser) is working properly. does anybody have an idea what could it be?

UPDATE: its not working in updateUser neither, only works in deleteUser

UPDATE 2: the updateUser and createNewUser are being called in my user form modal:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useContext, useCallback } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, toastContext } from "../trds";
import useUsers from "../hooks/useUsers";

const initialState = {
    email: '',
    name: '',
    role: 'viewer'
};

export default function UserFormModal({userData, isOpen, onClose}){

    const launchToast = useContext(toastContext);
    const { createNewUser, updateUser } = useUsers();

    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(userData) setData(userData);
    }, [userData]);

    const handleSubmit = async () => {

        if(!data.email || !data.name){
            return launchToast('You have to provide email and name!', 'error');
        }

        setIsLoading(true);

        if(userData){

            await updateUser(data)

        } else {

            await createNewUser(data);

        }

        setData(initialState);
        onClose();

        setIsLoading(false);

    }

    const handleClose = useCallback(() => {
        setData(initialState);
        onClose();
    }, [onClose]);

    return(

        <Modal
            title={userData ? 'Update user' : 'Create user'}
            isOpen={isOpen}
            onClose={handleClose}
        >

            <trds-stack style={{gap: 'var(--space--l)'}}>

                <input  
                    type="email"
                    name="userEmail"
                    placeholder="Email address"
                    value={data.email}
                    onChange={(e) => setData(prevState => ({...prevState, email: e.target.value}))}
                />

                <input  
                    type="text"
                    name="userName"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    value={data.name}
                    onChange={(e) => setData(prevState => ({...prevState, name: e.target.value}))}
                />

                <trds-stack style={{gap: 0}}>

                    <label>Role</label>

                    <select 
                        name="userRole" 
                        onChange={(e) => setData(prevState => ({...prevState, role: e.target.value}))} 
                        value={data.role}
                    >
                        <option value="viewer">Viewer</option>
                        <option value="technician">Technician</option>
                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                    </select>

                </trds-stack>

                <Button
                    text={userData ? 'Update user' : 'Create user'}
                    loading={isLoading}
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                />

            </trds-stack>

        </Modal>

    )
}
```

SO, it may have correlation...

Comment: Are you sure that `setUsers(returnedUsers)` is called?

Comment: yes, 100%. its for the initial state tho.